How to draw an up and down arrow on a closing switch in circuitikz
How can I draw an up and down arrow on a closing switch in circuitikz? Please see my current code, the output it produces, and the desired output below. Additionally, how can I add a comment "100kHz" above the switch?
My Code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}
    
        \draw (0,0) to[closing switch] (5,0);
    
    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}

My Output:

My Desired Output:


Add label=100kHZ for the label. The other should be easy, but not sure it is. (But I didn't look at the docs - maybe there's a different style of switch you could use?)

@crf: thanks a lot! do you know how to control the position of the label?

See at https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz, package documentation. Search for label (many hits) // For the arrows at the switch, see ch. "3.2.3 Descriptions" ...

If you have a recent version of circuitikz, the options for tuning the arrows work also for traditional switches (they used to work only for "cute" switches).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to[closing switch, switch start arrow=latexslim,
            l=\qty{100}{\kHz}] (5,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


adding label distance=10pt gives:

Relevant parts of the (current) manual: 4.21.5 Switch arrows (should be easy to spot...)

...and 5.1.1 Label and annotation position

